# jquery on(live function)

Tags: jquery

Why this code is not working?

```
$("div.class ul li").on("click","a",function(){
        alert("A");
});
```

But this works fine...

```
$("body").on("click","div.class ul li a",function(){
    alert("A");
});
```

Comment: `div.class ul li` probably doesn't exist when you're trying to attach your handler (where as `body` does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that your `div.class ul li` is dynamically created. You need to call `on` function on some existing element (closest parent for example). This is why it works when called on `body`.

Comment: but I have one more problem..now after click on <a> it shows me this error(in console)-"Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ." where is problem? I didn't find any solution because there is only "."

Comment: How you changed your code? In whot line of code you have such error? It looks like some mistake in the jquery expression.

Comment: Finally I found what was the problem..I have inside div 2 <ul> and 2 this functions: $("body").on("click","div.class ul li a",function(){, which each do other thing..(inside first was something like this: var a=$(this).attr("lightbox"), and this attribute wasnt inside second <ul>)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your code is dynamically inserting `li` elements after the page has loaded. For event delegation to work you'll want to bind to the nearest element (parent, grandparent, etc) which exists when the DOM is `ready`. The `ul` perhaps?

```
$("div.class ul").on("click","li a",function(){
  alert("A");
});
```